# How to eliminate cartesian product with joins while using subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, cartesian-product

I have the following database:

```
 paperid | authorid | name
---------+----------+---------------
 1889374 |   897449 | D. N. Page
 1889374 |  1795881 | C. N. Pope
 1889374 |  1952069 | S. W. Hawking
```

I would like to create a table having following columns:

- paperid
- author name - for each author of this paperid
- coauthors - for each coauthor of that paper

The result should look like this:

```
 paperid |    author     |          coauthors          
---------+---------------+---------------------------
 1889374 | D. N. Page    |  C. N. Pope S. W. Hawking
 1889374 | C. N. Pope    | D. N. Page  S. W. Hawking
 1889374 | S. W. Hawking | D. N. Page C. N. Pope
```

and this is achieved with following queries:

```
SELECT  foo.paperid, npa.name as author, foo.coauthors
INTO npatest
FROM newpaperauthor npa
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT paperid, string_agg(name, ' ') as coauthors
   FROM newpaperauthor
   GROUP BY paperid
   ORDER BY paperid) foo;
UPDATE npatest SET coauthors = regexp_replace(coauthors, author, '');
SELECT * FROM npatest;
```

The problem arise when there's more `paperid`s in the database like to :

```
 paperid | authorid |       name       |      affiliation       
---------+----------+------------------+------------------------
 1889373 |   122817 | Kazuhiro Hongo   | 
 1889373 |  1091191 | Hiroshi NAKAGAWA | 
 1889373 |  1874415 | Hiroshi Nakagawa | University of Oklahoma
 1889373 |  2149773 | Han Soo Chang    | 
 1889374 |   897449 | D. N. Page       | 
 1889374 |  1795881 | C. N. Pope       | 
 1889374 |  1952069 | S. W. Hawking    |
```

Then I will get a cartesian product of them like:

```
 paperid |      author      |                           coauthors                            
---------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 1889373 | Kazuhiro Hongo   |  Hiroshi NAKAGAWA Hiroshi Nakagawa Han Soo Chang
 1889374 | Kazuhiro Hongo   | D. N. Page C. N. Pope S. W. Hawking
 1889373 | Hiroshi NAKAGAWA | Kazuhiro Hongo  Hiroshi Nakagawa Han Soo Chang
 1889374 | Hiroshi NAKAGAWA | D. N. Page C. N. Pope S. W. Hawking
 1889373 | Hiroshi Nakagawa | Kazuhiro Hongo Hiroshi NAKAGAWA  Han Soo Chang
 1889374 | Hiroshi Nakagawa | D. N. Page C. N. Pope S. W. Hawking
 1889373 | Han Soo Chang    | Kazuhiro Hongo Hiroshi NAKAGAWA Hiroshi Nakagawa 
 1889374 | Han Soo Chang    | D. N. Page C. N. Pope S. W. Hawking
 1889373 | D. N. Page       | Kazuhiro Hongo Hiroshi NAKAGAWA Hiroshi Nakagawa Han Soo Chang
 1889374 | D. N. Page       |  C. N. Pope S. W. Hawking
 1889373 | C. N. Pope       | Kazuhiro Hongo Hiroshi NAKAGAWA Hiroshi Nakagawa Han Soo Chang
 1889374 | C. N. Pope       | D. N. Page  S. W. Hawking
 1889373 | S. W. Hawking    | Kazuhiro Hongo Hiroshi NAKAGAWA Hiroshi Nakagawa Han Soo Chang
 1889374 | S. W. Hawking    | D. N. Page C. N. Pope
```

How to get rid of that cartesian product there ?

Comment: Would you like to sort coauthors in any particular way?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter not really, it doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be **surprisingly simple** with [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) as window aggregate function combined with [`array_remove()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) (introduced with pg 9.3):

```
CREATE TABLE npatest AS
SELECT paperid, name AS author
     , array_to_string(array_remove(array_agg(name) OVER (PARTITION BY paperid), name), ', ') AS coauthors
FROM   newpaperauthor n;
```

If author names are not unique, there are complications.
Then again, if author names are not unique, your whole operation is flawed.

Using `array_agg()` and `array_remove()` instead of `string_agg()` and `regexp_replace()`, because the latter would fail easily for similar names like 'Jon Fox' and 'Jon Foxy', and also be messy with delimiters.

[`array_to_string()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) transforms the array to a string. I used `', '` as separator, which seems more sensible to me than just a space.

The use of [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-selectinto.html) is discouraged. Use the superior [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html) instead. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-selectinto.html#AEN81072)

> `CREATE TABLE AS` is the recommended syntax, since this form of
>   `SELECT INTO` is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they
>   interpret the `INTO` clause differently. Furthermore, `CREATE TABLE AS`
>   offers a superset of the functionality provided by `SELECT INTO`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fae38/1)

Comment: Your query is quite simple yet it returns the coauthors in JSON array format like :`1 | Mahmoud Refaat | {"Motaz Ahmad El-saban","Ayman Kaheel","Ahmed Abdul-hamid"}`

Comment: @Patryk: That's not JSON format but the Postgres text representation of the array. I left instructions how to convert to text with `array_to_string()`. Spelled it out now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to approach this problem:

Generate the list of all co-authors as a subquery.  Generate the list of all authors.  Then join these together and do the string manipulation to get what you want.

---

The authors is easy:

```
select paperid, npa.name as author
from newpaperauthor npa;
```

The co-authors is easy:

```
select paperid, string_agg(npa.name, ' ') as coauthors
from newpaperauthor npa
group by paperid;
```

The combination requires some list substitution:

```
select a.paperid, a.author,
       replace(replace(coauthors, author, ''), '  ', ' ') as coauthors
from (select paperid, npa.name as author
      from newpaperauthor npa
     ) a join
     (select paperid, string_agg(npa.name, ' ') as coauthors
      from newpaperauthor npa
      group by paperid
     ) ca
     on a.paperid = ca.paperid;
```

Comment: I had to change last line to `on a.paperid = ca.paperid;` because it was giving me `argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type bigint`. Thanks :)

Comment: @Patryk . . . That was a typo.  Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

@GordonLinoff 's query can be simplified a bit by suppressing the 1st author in the aggregate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        p0.paperid , p0.authorid , p0.name as name1
        , string_agg(p1.name, ', ' ) AS others
FROM papers p0
JOIN papers p1 ON p1.paperid = p0.paperid AND p1.authorid <> p0.authorid
GROUP BY p0.paperid, p0.authorid, p0.name
ORDER BY p0.paperid, p0.authorid
        ;
```